# Userform listbox (multiple cols) to edit values and update sheet & list

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a userform in Excel which has a listbox which pulls data from a dynamic range (5 columns, 1 being a unique ID number).

When the user clicks the record it displays each value in a text box and the ID number in a label.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
  Me.Label6 = Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 0) 'record number
  Me.TextBox1 = Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 4)'Staff name
  Me.TextBox2 = Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)'Strategy
  Me.TextBox3 = Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 2)'Notes
  Me.TextBox4 = Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 3)'Date
End Sub
```

I want the user to makes changes to the record and update the list box and data on sheet.  It is updating the right record just with one value!

[User form with updated same value in all columns see rec# 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvCHn.png)

```
Private Sub CMDUpdate_Click()

Dim erowa As Integer
Dim x  As Integer

erowa = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet9.Range("A:A"))

For x = 2 To erowa

   If Sheet9.Cells(x, "A").Value = Me.Label6 Then  'this is the unique ID

       Sheet9.Cells(x, "B").Value = Me.TextBox1.Value 'Staff name
       Sheet9.Cells(x, "C").Value = Me.TextBox2.Value 'Strategy
       Sheet9.Cells(x, "D").Value = Me.TextBox3.Value 'Notes 
       Sheet9.Cells(x, "E").Value = Me.TextBox4.Value 'date

   End If
Next

End Sub
```

Also date format for some reason displays the Julian value!

I spent a whole day researching, watching tutorials, reading blogs.

Comment: your code is updating the whole range with the current values in the text boxes. You'd need to look for the record and update is accordingly

Comment: Does Me.Label6 returns the record row in the sheet?

Comment: Oh OK well that makes sense thank you!  Do you have any suggestions on what I code I could use?

Comment: Is it the case?

Comment: label 6 is a unique value for each row. @ Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of finding the value in Me.Label6 and updating the cells next to it

```
Private Sub CMDUpdate_Click()

    Dim cell As Range

    Set cell = sheet9.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Me.Label6.Caption, _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)

    If Not cell Is Nothing Then

        ' Column B
        cell.Offset(, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value 'Staff name
        ' Column C
        cell.Offset(, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value 'Strategy
        ' Column D
        cell.Offset(, 3).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value 'Notes
        ' Column E
        cell.Offset(, 4).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value 'date

    Else

        MsgBox "Record: " & Me.Label6.Caption & " not found in column A!"

    End If

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works!